# WordPress - query doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, price

I'm having some troubles with wordpress query.

I need to modify the "_regular_price" meta_value through query with a given post_id.

The code to get the post_id works well, but the query doesn't update its regular price.

Here's my script...

```
foreach (get_zomatik() as $key => $value)
{
    $producto = $value->nombre;
    $sku      = $value->codigo;
    $stock    = $value->stock;
    $precio   = $value->precio;

    // prod_id works well...
    $prod_id  = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value='%s'", $sku))[0];
    echo $prod_id . "<br>";

    // this doesn't work... :(
    $sql = "UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value='".$precio."' WHERE meta_key='_regular_price' AND post_id='".$prod_id."'";
    $wpdb->query($sql);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is your code located?

Comment: Is located in the following path: html/script (html is the root folder by default).

Comment: your website(wordpress) folder is `/script`? what the name of file your code located in? how do you called it?

Comment: I saw the comment under the answer. you should add the code or the url into the question( by editing it ). are you sure, that `wp-load.php` file was called?

Comment: What is get_zomatik() function, where is it defined? Remember that *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**."*…

Comment: get_zomatik is a function which returns an object from an external json (my enterprise's local server). I debugged it before and so it DOES return all needed data. If you need to read the full code, you can visit this link https://pastebin.com/Uts7PuAW

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the raw query that the [`update_post_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) generates.

But – so far as you're using "post meta" interface that WordPress has implicitly defined, it's a good idea to update it using their functions.

So, something like:

```
update_post_meta($prod_id, '_regular_price', $precio);
```

in your loop should take care of generating and executing the correct query for updating the `_regular_price` post meta for a given `$prod_id`.

Comment: Such a "do my work for me" response. What's the return value?

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't return any bounce back error message, and it has me a little bit dizzy ... I tried also prepare(), but did not work too... If you need the full code, here's what I have: https://pastebin.com/Uts7PuAW

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump(update_post_meta($prod_id, '_regular_price', $precio));`

Comment: I fixed!, none of the given answers worked, so I decided to use native PHP running mySQLi commands, searching into meta_key and post_id columns, and so it worked well...